# Sitecore 9 Platform Essentials Module 7 - Error Rendering Controller: Related Events when using an Edit Frame

Tags: experience-editor, controller, training

I am working through the training for Sitecore 9 Platform Essentials. I am on Module 7 where they have you work on the Related Events controller and show you how to make a complex field editable in the Experience Editor. I have followed all of the directions and have added my edit frame around the Related Events component. In the core database, I have created a Field Editor button under /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/RelatedEvents/ and named it "Edit Related Events". I have added an icon to the button and assigned it to the field "RelatedEvents". I have assigned related events to this Climbing Item. When I view the Event Details page in the Experience Editor the page displays fine. As soon as I click on the Edit button in the Experience Editor the error displays in the pageSide placeholder. I have published all of the files. I do not know what is causing this error. I have googled it but haven't found a solution. Hoping someone can help me out.

Thank you.

The error says:

```
Error Rendering Controller: RelatedEvents. Action: Index: An unhandled exception occurred.
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

Screenshot of page receiving error
[image]

RelatedEventsController screenshot
[image]

RelatedEventsProvider.cs screenshot
[image]

RelatedEvents View screenshot
[image]

RelatedEvents Controller Rendering screenshot
[image]

Comment: Excellent detail in the question! I don't know the answer, but a few questions: If you set a debug point in your controller, does it get hit? Are you able to debug to the point where the exception occurs? This helps you identify where the error is happening.

Also, do you have a more specific error in the Sitecore log files? The error you provided the stacktrace for looks pretty generic, so there may be something more helpful in the log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the very detailed question!

Based on your description for how you created the Edit Frame Buttons and how you are referencing them, I suspect that the path the buttons is incorrect. Specifically, you said that you created the buttons at `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/RelatedEvents/`, yet, your parameter reads `Related Events` in your View screenshot.

The `@Html.EditFrame()` extension method takes a "Buttons" parameter that is used to attempt to match a *folder name* under `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons` which should contain one or more Edit Frame buttons underneath it.

See also:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/using_editframes

Steps #2 and #7 under the Edit Frames Buttons section of this blog post: http://www.awareweb.com/awareblog/11-25-14-custombuttonspageeditor

Comment: Thank you Derek for your help. Changing the parameter to "RelatedEvents" in the EditFrame in the View fixed the problem. There was a typo in the Student Lab and it said to type it as "Related Events".